# What's the differences between Rate and InterArrival time?

Tags: anylogic

I learned that Rate follows Exponential Distribution.

In that case, if I set

(1) Defined by : Rate and Arrival Rate value : 2
or

(2) Defined by : InterArrival time and InterArrival time value: exponential(2)

Could I conclude that (1) and (2) are same ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below question/answer might help you:
[Is AnyLogic's arrival rate a Poisson distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62405703/is-anylogics-arrival-rate-a-poisson-distribution)

But in short, the answer to your question is yes, your two scenarios represent the same behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65040041/how-to-prove-arrival-rate-follows-exponential-distributions/65040289#65040289

Also refer to my answer to this question. You can track the actual distributions as your model is running for the two scenarios and compare the results to visually see it.

Comment: Thank you. If they are same, why they are seperated??

Comment: Because you may assign a fixed interarrival rate, or something different than exponential. They are only the same when you use exponential.

Comment: Aha, I almost got it. Could I ask the last question? What do you mean 
' something different than exponential ' ?

Comment: The interarrival time is the time between each arrival. So you may specify this time as 1 hour. In that case each 1 hour, an agent will arrive (this would be a constant). You can specify a triangular, uniform, etc. any distribution to represent that time. Exponential is just one of the many available distributions. You may even add a custom distribution.

Comment: Oh god.. I really appreciate it. Have a nice day :)